# Integrating LDAP with Application (Jasper on tomcat)

Tags: java, spring, ldap, jasperserver

I am working on integrating my reporting app with LDAP, I modified a few beans in the applicationContext-externalAuth-LDAP.xml as per the documentation

1) ldapContextSource

```
<bean id="ldapContextSource" class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.ldap.JSLdapContextSource">
        <constructor-arg value="ldap://url.ldap.com:3268/DC=main,DC=com"/>
        <!-- manager user name and password (may not be needed)  -->
        <property name="userDn" value="CN=Account Name,OU=Support User Account,DC=main,DC=com"/>
        <property name="password" value="123xyz"/>
</bean>
```

2) userSearch bean

```
    <bean id="userSearch"
          class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.wrappers.spring.ldap.JSFilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
        <constructor-arg index="0">
            <value>(&amp;(|(objectClass=contact)(objectClass=user))(objectCategory=person)(cn={0})(|(memberOf=CN=VPN-Access,CN=Users,DC=Main,DC=com)(memberOf=CN=All,CN=Disto,CN=Users,DC=main,DC=com)))</value>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index="1">
            <value>(&amp;(sAMAccountName={0}))</value>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index="2">
            <ref local="ldapContextSource" />
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="searchSubtree">
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I tested the above search string connection using jexplorer and it successfully retrieved my users.

The error I'm getting when I deploy this to my app is. Any ideas as to what the root cause of this would be or the solution would be greatly appreciated:

````
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: Failed to parse DN; nested exception is org.springframework.ldap.core.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1, column 1.  Encountered: "(" (40), after : ""
Caused by: org.springframework.ldap.BadLdapGrammarException: Failed to parse DN; nested exception is org.springframework.ldap.core.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1, column 1.  Encountered: "(" (40), after : ""
Caused by: org.springframework.ldap.core.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1, column 1.  Encountered: "(" (40), after : ""```
````

Comment: `at line 1, column 1.  Encountered: "(" (40), after : ""` it seems like there is a non-printable (illegal) character at the very beginning of a dn string. Check your config files in a file editor that shows such characters (vi).

Comment: @EricLavault not sure what that characted would be. I viewed the document using vi as well as notepad++ with show all characters on. The beginning of my usersearch string does have and "(" but i'm not sure why that would be illegal.

Comment: I was referring to the `""` (that comes before) as a non printable character which  might be represented with weird symbols in a text editor.

Comment: @EricLavault you're right, for some reason it didn't like my value in the first constructor-arg. I was testing the string on jexplorer but for whatever reason it doesn't seem to take the same notation. Sorry I can't provide a reason for this but if anyone is seeing this issue, my problem was related to that. I changed it to CN=Disto,CN=Users,DC=main,DC=com and it works fine. Thanks.